# Missing AWS properties when creating AWS application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I'm struggling to figure out how to add AWS properties to my application.properties (or application.yml) file, and I'm not sure what I have set up incorrectly in STS.

I can reproduce this creating a simple AWS app using Spring Initializr. I'm adding AWS, Consul and REST because that's what the real app is using.  Here's the POM it generates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>edu.dkist</groupId>
<artifactId>staging-service-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>staging-service-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

I'm not adding any code to the application for this sample, only the code that is generated. This was a test to see if something was wrong with the app I was working on. When I try to add an application property, nothing shows for AWS. The same is true if I create a YAML file.

[image: Missing AWS properties]

If I force the issue, and add it anyway STS says the property is unknown.

[image: Unknown property aws]

Compiling the app throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is not EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance
```

The app is not running on an EC2 instance, it's running locally. From what I've read I need to add the aws.region.auto if it's not running on EC2, but I can't get the app to acknowledge the property exists. Same happens with the access key and secret key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... after lots of tinkering and reading other posts it looks like the properties will work if you add them, even if STS doesn't recognize them.

I added

```
cloud:   
  aws:
  credentials:
    instanceProfile: false
  region:
    static: eu-west-1
  stack:
    auto: false
```

and the program will run.

The other thing that was tripping me up is the inconsistency in the paths for the properties. For example Consul properties are at

```
spring.cloud.consul.*
```

where as AWS is at

```
cloud.aws.*
```

There's no "spring" to start the AWS properties. I'm sure there is a reason for the inconsistency, I just don't know it.

Comment: STS 'recognizing' properties depends on the availability of metadata for those properties on the classpath. It is up to library authors to provide the metadata. So my guess would be the AWS properties don't have proper metadata. Probably because the library authors didn't create it.

Comment: if you want to know more about the configuration metadata that STS uses behind the scenes and that is being generated by Spring Boot for its own configurations, here is the reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html